# Terraform: How to share resource from shared modules to environment specific modules?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

Firstly, my terminology might be poor as I'm just starting out with Terraform, so I apologize.

I have the following structure on my infrastructure Terraform project:

```
├── environments
│   ├── dev
│   ├── staging
│   └── prod
├── modules
│   ├── iam
│   ├── lambda
│   ├── s3
│   ├── ...
│   └── security
├── shared
│   ├── containers
│   ├── iam
│   ├── ...
│   └── s3
└── main.tf
```

So a little bit context: I am using the `/environments/` directory for creating custom resources for each application environment. Those resources are created based on the modules defined on the `/modules/` directory, and that's what I'm referring with "environment specific modules".

On the `/shared/` directory I have modules which are used the same for all environments. Those are used on `/main.tf` and applied when `terraform apply` runs on root.

There are cases when I want to reference a shared resource inside an environment. For example a container (AWS ECR) shared upon all environments. The `repository_url` of this container will be the same while the image tag will change. How can I reference it inside `/modules/lambda/main.tf` for example? I though about using a variable on the `lambda` module, so the value can be specified when the module is created on `environments/dev/main.tf`, but how can I reference it?

I thought about having the following code on `environments/dev/main.tf`:

```
module "containers" {
    source = "../../shared/containers/"
}

module "lambda" {
    source        = "../../modules/lambda/"
    container_url = module.containers.lambda_repository_url
}
```

but wouldn't that recreate the resources on the shared modules each time the environment is applied?

Comment: If I understood your question, you would like to fetch the attributes exported by resources from the modules you call. You can do that with output values. Read more here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if using them you'll need to define the module. Wouldn't that recreate the resources on that module?

Comment: So you are not invoking the shared modules from the same `main.tf`?

Comment: Exactly. I'm invoking shared modules from the root `/main.tf`. The `/environments/dev/main.tf` invokes resource specific for the environment. However, inside that `main.tf` I'd like to reference some of the resource already created by the root `/main.tf` (shared resources). Is that possible? If not, how can I restructure the code so it can be possible.

Comment: You could use data sources for that, depending on the resource of course. Or if you are willing to undertake another adventure, then I think terragrunt fits your use case.